# In Sql Server, how do you put value from cursor into temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, database-cursor

I am trying to create a function which has a cursor in it. I want to get the Quanatity value from that cursor and put it in the temp table. But I havent succeeded to get the value and put it into the temp table.

I put comment where I couldnt get it done...

here is my code

```
alter FUNCTION test(@input VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS Decimal(8, 2) AS BEGIN

DECLARE @rst Decimal(8, 2) SET @rst=0
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Quantity Decimal(8,2), Price Decimal(8,2))
DECLARE @amount Decimal(8,2)
DECLARE @price Decimal(8,2)

DECLARE CrsOrfLine CURSOR FOR
SELECT AMOUNT FROM LG_001_01_ORFLINE 
 WHERE LINETYPE    = 0 
 AND ORDFICHEREF = (SELECT TOP 1 LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_01_ORFICHE WHERE GUID='EEB44E72-3717-4F5B-8F7E-6A36EB38EA22')
 ORDER BY LINENO_ ASC;

FETCH NEXT FROM CrsOrfLine INTO  @amount
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @Temp (Quantity)

     /* HOW AM I SUPPOSED TO ADD IT INTO THE TEMP?????? */
     /* I COULDNT FIGURE THIS PART OUT                  */

FETCH NEXT FROM CrsOrfLine INTO @amount
END /*WHILE*/
CLOSE CrsOrfLine
DEALLOCATE CrsOrfLine
```

Comment: You'd use `INSERT INTO @Temp (Quantity) VALUES (@Amount)` - **However** there is almost certainly a better way, the performance of this function will be dreadful! Seems like [an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You may want to describe what you are trying to achieve with your function and get answers to that, rather than how to get around a problem in your solution.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a cursor to load a temp table?

Comment: You can either `SELECT INTO...`, which will create the table for you, or declare it and `INSERT INTO...SELECT`.

Comment: Although I don't think a cursor is an appropriate solution here, you should also get in the habit of declaring an appropriate cursor for your needs, i.e. if you are only reading from the cursor use `READ_ONLY`, if you only ever use `FETCH NEXT`, use `FORWARD_ONLY` etc. This avoids redundant memory usage and can significantly improve the performance of the cursor.

Comment: And by the way if you build a cursor with a SELECT TOP 1 query, your cursor will only run once (for the one row returned by the query) and then end.  Always.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Not only do you have a cursor it is inside a scalar function. I am guessing this could be turned into an inline table valued function. It would blow the doors off for performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following. Note that it only inserts the quantity so it needs to be modified if you intend to include the price.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE 
(
  Quantity Decimal(8,2), 
  Price Decimal(8,2)
)


INSERT INTO @temp (Quantity)
SELECT AMOUNT FROM LG_001_01_ORFLINE 
WHERE LINETYPE = 0 
AND ORDFICHEREF = (SELECT TOP 1 LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_01_ORFICHE WHERE GUID='EEB44E72-3717-4F5B-8F7E-6A36EB38EA22 ORDER BY LINENO_ ASC')
```

Comment: yes, I need to add price as well but I am not sure how to update it. any idea?

Comment: How do you get the price? Does it come from the same `SELECT`?

Comment: SELECT ORG_PRICE 
   FROM LG_XT002001_001 XT002 
  WHERE XT002.ORF_GUID='EEB44E72-3717-4F5B-8F7E-6A36EB38EA22'
  ORDER BY ORFLINE_NO ASC;

Comment: I'd rewrite the query to get the 2 columns in one select if possible. Then you could either remove `(quantity)` from my query or change it to `(quantity, price)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_demo_cursor_with_temp_table]              
AS              
BEGIN  
DECLARE @temp TABLE  (value1 varchar(5),value2 varchar(5),value3 INT,value4 varchar(1))

DECLARE @value1 varchar(5)
DECLARE @value2 varchar(5) 
DECLARE @value3 INT
DECLARE @value4 varchar(5)

DECLARE check_data_cursor CURSOR FOR 

select distinct value1,value2,value3,value4 from table_name where status = 'A'

OPEN check_data_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM check_data_cursor INTO @value1,@value2,@value3,@value4

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)

BEGIN
-- any business logic + temp inseration 

insert into @temp values (@tickerCode,@quarter,@financial_year,@status)
 END 

 FETCH NEXT FROM check_data_cursor  INTO @value1,@value2,@value3,@value4
 END

 CLOSE check_data_cursor

 DEALLOCATE check_data_cursor

 -- to view temp data

 select * from @temp          

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited: This should help taking care of the price. Since the price is coming from a different `Select` statement, you may need a `join` here.

```
INSERT INTO @Temp (Quantity, Price)
(SELECT AMOUNT FROM LG_001_01_ORFLINE 
WHERE LINETYPE    = 0 
AND ORDFICHEREF = (SELECT TOP 1 LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_01_ORFICHE WHERE GUID='EEB44E72-3717-4F5B-8F7E-6A36EB38EA22' ORDER BY LINENO_ ASC)) T1
JOIN 
(SELECT ORG_PRICE FROM LG_XT002001_001 XT002 WHERE XT002.ORF_GUID='EEB44E72-3717-4F5B-8F7E-6A36EB38EA22' ORDER BY ORFLINE_NO ASC) T2
ON T1.Primary_Key = T2.Primary_Key
```